# Find lowest number from column in table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables - EVENT, MEMBER, RANK. I need to show the best result (from RANK) along with the member it belongs to, for a specific event (ex EVENT01) What is the simplest way to do this? My code below seems to select the lowest number, but duplicates itself and claims other members got the same result.

Expected output:

```
EVENT_ID    EVENT_TYPE    EVENT_NAME    MEMBER_ID    MEMBER_NAME    RESULT
event01     swimming      100m          mem001       John Smith     10
```

Code so far:

```
SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME, R.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME, (SELECT MIN(RESULT)
FROM RANK WHERE E.EVENT_ID = 'EVENT003' ) AS AVG_INCOME_ALL_CLUBS
FROM EVENT E, RANK R, MEMBER M
WHERE E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID
AND R.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID
ORDER BY MEMBER_ID;
```

Comment: Doesn't every event have a winner? Why can't you simply filter (use a WHERE clause) on R.RESULT = 1?

Answer (score 0):

First, learn to use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Second, the answer to your question is `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME, R.MEMBER_ID, M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.EVENT_ID ORDER BY R.RESULT ASC) as SEQNUM
      FROM EVENT E, JOIN
           RANK R
           ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID JOIN
           MEMBER M 
           ON R.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID
    ) ERM
WHERE SEQNUM = 1
ORDER BY MEMBER_ID;
```

Comment: Might be better using `RANK` since in the case of a tie, `ROW_NUMBER` will pick one arbitrarily.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp . . . If you want duplicates in the case of a tie, then use `rank()` or `dense_rank()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT E.EVENT_ID, E.EVENT_TYPE, E.EVENT_NAME, R.MEMBER_ID,M.MEMBER_FIRSTNAME, M.MEMBER_LASTNAME,
 FROM EVENT E, JOIN
       RANK R
       ON E.EVENT_ID = R.EVENT_ID JOIN
       MEMBER M 
       ON R.MEMBER_ID = M.MEMBER_ID
       where R.RESULT=
 (SELECT MIN(RESULT) FROM RANK WHERE E.EVENT_ID = 'EVENT003') AND R.EVENT_ID='EVENT003';
```